# How To match Any string with file extension in a line and print only the matching word in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I wanted to search and match any word followed by file extension .log.gz in a line and print only the matching word.

Below is the code example I tried,

```
# Global Import Variables
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

line = "helo how are helloo.log.gz you"

line_se = re.search(r"\b.*\.log.gz", line)


if line_se:
    print line_se
    print("yo it's a {}".format(line_se.group(0)))
```

But the output is the whole line until the extension like 
`yo it's a helo how are helloo.log.gz`, but the output I wanted is just `helloo.log.gz`. Can anyone correct me on the reg exp which I am using to print out the matching word with the extension !

Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.*` to `\S*` so it doesn't match spaces.

```
ine_se = re.search(r"\S*\.log\.gz", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a regex for this. Built-in string methods will suffice. For example,

```
from functools import partial

def find_filename(text, extension):
    """Finds the first word in 'text' that ends with 'extension.',
    or 'None' if 'text' doesn't contain such a word."""
    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.endswith('.' + extension):
            return word

find_log_gz = partial(find_filename, extension="log.gz")

# Test:
>>> find_log_gz("helo how are helloo.log.gz you")
'helloo.log.gz'
>>>
```